# Merging two php objects or arrays on specific value

Tags: php, merge, array-merge

I have issue with merge of two objects in PHP as I need to merge them only if specific values on specific keys match.

Table 1 users:

```
id | name | email | ....

1 | first | some@ | ....
```

This table have more data but I don't think that's important for this question.

table 2 service:

```
id | userID | phone | ....

1  |1        | 12345
```

The tables look super ugly so I'll show how result looks like:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#227 (5) { 
      ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
      ["name"]=> string(4) "rade" 
      ["email"]=> string(13) "mail@mail.com" 
      ...
```

and second one:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (24) { 
      ["ID"]=> string(2) "20" 
      ["userID"]=> string(1) "1" 
      ["phone"]=> string(4) "6541"
```

I may not have same number of results in both arrays, first one may and will have more, and I need to merge them when id of first one matches userID of second one. I have done this with nesting two foreach loops but I hate that way, when database have 1000 of each it will be 1 mil of loops.

```
foreach($objONE as $one) {
    foreach($objTWO as $two) {
        if($two->userID == $one->id) {
            $name = $one->name;
            $phone = $two->phone; 
            //and i use all data
        }
    }
}
```

I use results right away so there is no need to keep them as object, they can be converted to arrays. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you simply extract the records from both tables using [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)? I assume that you are using some kind of query language to get the data.

Comment: This is not about the PHP work but the SQL. Show us your query and we can help at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Wazelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119450/wazelin) and [nerdlyist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612651/nerdlyist) I was looking at this problem wrong way, this was SQL not PHP problem, I just edited mine query and I got results that I need, and once again thanks [Wazelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119450/wazelin) for pointing me in right direction, left join did great job, ill post code so someone with similar issue can find solution faster ;)

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN service ON users.id=service.userID WHERE users.grupa = 'service'
```